# Is it possible to make only xhr request for login functionality in every test in Cypress without UI interaction?

Tags: cypress

I would like to login without using UI elements for my endpoint testing in Cypress. I've tried to use only XHR without interaction with any UI element. This approach will be only for xhr testing. 
The problem is that in my API/XHT testing I would like only use endpoints and reduce interacting with UI elements to minimum.

Comment: Please state your question in the form of a question.

Comment: You should avoid using your Login Form. This is bad practise because in most cases you will not want to test your Login form all the time. So yes, you can login through XHR request. For a more detailed answer you should clearify your question